# cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Tags: php, curl, guzzle6, guzzle

I use Guzzle in my Laravel 5.8 project

I'm trying to make a GET to a URL (signed cert) serve on `https`

"https://172.1.1.1:443/accounts"

```
public static function get($url) {

    // dd($url);

    try {
        $client = new Client();
        $options = [
            'http_errors'     => true,
            'connect_timeout' => 3.14,
            'read_timeout'    => 3.14,
            'timeout'         => 3.14,
            'curl'            => array(
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
            )

        ];

        $headers = [
            'headers' => [
                'Keep-Alive' => 'timeout=300'
            ]
        ];

        $result = $client->request('GET', $url, $headers, $options);


        // dd($result);



    } catch (ConnectException $e) {

        //Logging::error($e);

        return null;
    }

    return json_decode($result->getBody(), true);
}
```

I used these 2 flags already

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
URLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
```

I'm not sure why I kept getting,

[image]

Comment: Did you configured your php.ini with cacert? https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1935#issuecomment-371756738 (or the answer below) with a custom certificate

Comment: According to the PHP docs, the value of `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` should be numeric, not boolean (specifically: `0` to turn it off [**not recommended in production**]). See [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

Answer (score 1):

the only sensible explanation (short of [cosmic rays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_error#Cosmic_rays_creating_energetic_neutrons_and_protons) and ram errors) is that Client (whatever Client is) is either overriding your custom curl settings, or ignoring them. there should be no way to get that error with `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` & `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` disabled.

... btw if that is a Guzzle\Client, have you tried adding `'verify' => 'false'` to $options ? that's supposedly the guzzle-way of disabling it, wouldn't surprise me if Guzzle is overriding your custom settings because of Guzzle's `verify` option not being disabled (it's [enabled by default](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#verify))

Answer (score 0):

I'm agree with @hanshenrik, I tested it and it's the exact problem. By default the client you create have the following configuration:

```
$defaults = [
            'allow_redirects' => RedirectMiddleware::$defaultSettings,
            'http_errors'     => true,
            'decode_content'  => true,
            'verify'          => true,
            'cookies'         => false
        ];
```

So you have to change it to:

```
public static function get($url) {

    // dd($url);

    try {
        $client = new Client(['verify' => false]);
        $options = [
            'http_errors'     => true,
            'connect_timeout' => 3.14,
            'read_timeout'    => 3.14,
            'timeout'         => 3.14
            )
        ];

        $headers = [
            'headers' => [
                'Keep-Alive' => 'timeout=300'
            ]
        ];

        $result = $client->request('GET', $url, $headers, $options);


        // dd($result);



    } catch (ConnectException $e) {

        //Logging::error($e);

        return null;
    }

    return json_decode($result->getBody(), true);
}
```